# Python .join how to make some of the columns in the CSV file

Tags: csv, join, beautifulsoup, output

I found the mark (") as the pinchers and can not split it into multiple columns in the CSV file.

output :

```
"https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_ab305ff4-e19f-489e-bcdc-113aeb7581ea.jpg, https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_8d47964f-75af-42bc-9af8-b60e4562ae01.jpg, https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_9cc59e50-ac85-4046-83df-ae3f53042f19.jpg, https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_48cf7f0e-b70c-424d-8000-5ca7f842b1e3.jpg, https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_2cce9f72-85dd-4006-a306-d7bbf83a45e4.jpg"
```

code :

```
f.writerow([(", ".join([link.get('href') for link in v.find_all('a')]))])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writerow` is not write"raw", it takes first param as list and formats it to each column.

`f.writerow( [link.get('href') for link in v.find_all('a')])`

See: https://pymotw.com/2/csv/#writing